# How do I copy the values of a HTML table column to the clipboard using a Django template and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, clipboard

I need to copy the values of a HTML table column to the clipboard. I'm using Django templates.

## **Here is my HTML table:**

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Guardian</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Telephone</th>
                        <th>NIF</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for a in sessao.first %}
                       <tr>
                          <td>{{ a.nome }}</td>
                          <td>{{ a.dtnasc }}</td>
                          <td>{{ a.alunoid }}</td>
                          <td>{{ a.educaid }}</td>
                          <td id="a.id">{{ a.educaid.email }}</td>
                          <td>{{ a.educaid.telefonea }}</td>
                          <td>{{ a.nif }}</td>
                          <td>{{ a.notas }}</td>
                          <td><button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" onclick="CopyText({{ a.id }})" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copy">
                               copy
                           </button>
                          </td> 
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

## **I'm trying this script but I get an error message:**

```
// Copy to ClipBoard
 function CopyText(el) {
 // Get the Selected Data By ID
  var copyText = document.getElementById(`${el}`)

  var str = copyText.innerHTML // Get All HTML Data and Copy to Clipboard

   function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

The error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
    at CopyText (lu.js:11:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (2/:80:159)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<td id="a.id">` - Did you mean `<td id="{{ a.id }}">` like you have in every other use of server-side object properties?

Comment: you're absolutely right. But the button is on each row now and I need to copy the entire table column values. How can I do that?

Comment: That sounds very different from what's shown in the code currently.  If you need to get data from every row of the table then you may need to loop over the table rows and aggregate the data however you need to.  For example, you may loop over the results of `document.querySelectorAll('tr')` and, within that loop, use `querySelector` on each `<tr>` element to get the target `<td>` element.  Though there could be a selector which returns the N-th `<td>` for every `<tr>` in one shot, which would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

In this case because your `id` attribute is set as a plain string and the element you are trying to retrieve does not exist. Also, the function param is not being passed correctly:

```
<table>
    ...

    {% for a in sessao.first %}
    <tr>
        ...
        <td id="a-{{a.id}}">{{ a.educaid.email }}</td>
        ...
        <td><button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" onclick="CopyText('{{a.id}}')" data-toggle="tooltip"
                data-placement="top" title="Copy">
                copy
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<script>
    const CopyText = (id) => {
        const text = document.getElementById(`a-${id}`).innerHTML;
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    }
</script>
```